# rails click image to play audio

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make it possible to play an audio file when clicking on an image. I am currently working with the latest version of Ruby on Rails. I found this code from a different post.

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('yourAudioTag').play();">
 <img src="yourSrc.jpg">
</a>
```

I am having trouble importing it. I am not sure if I have to setup Javascript with rails. I am currently putting the code in assets/javascripts,application.js. Are there any procedures I must take before Javascript can work with rails?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `yourAudioTag` with the actual DOM query selector.

So, if you name your audio tag like:

```
<audio id="rock-on" src="some_audio.mp3"></audio>
```

You'll have to replace `document.getElementById('yourAudioTag').play();` with `document.getElementById('rock-on').play();`.

Comment: <audio id="rock-on" src="some_audio.mp3"></audio>

So, do I put that line of code in my html file?

Comment: @vnbrs `document.getElementById('#rock-on').play();` should be `document.getElementById('rock-on').play();`